# sending multidimensional object -> last part is lost

Tags: php, jquery

I'm sending a multidimensional object with an ajax post request but some times the last part of the object is lost? Is there some kind of limit to how much data you can send?

### --------

### update

when counting the childs in `data.accounts` before the ajax post the number is 221, and when counting the `data.accounts` in the success handler the number is still 221

### The data being sent is at the most 10kb

---

When I do this right before the object is sent with ajax, all data is represented

```
var arr = [];
for(var key in obj){
    arr[arr.length] = key+' = '+obj[key];
}

alert(arr.join('\n'));
```

But when doing this on the backend the last part of the data is lost

```
print_r($data);
```

data structure (there are over 200 childs in `data.accounts` but only 198 are recieved)

```
    Array
    (
        [account_id_] => 0
        [name] => 1
        [type] => 2
        [type_pl] => Drift
        [type_b] => Status
        [type_p] => 
        [type_h] => Tekst
        [type_t] => Sum
        [att_sumfrom] => 4
        [vatcode] => 3
        [accounts] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [account_id_] => 1
                        [name] => OMS�TNING
                        [type] => 3
                        [att_sumfrom] => 
                        [vatcode] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [account_id_] => 1000
                        [name] => Varesalg
                        [type] => 0
                        [att_sumfrom] => 
                        [vatcode] => S25
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [account_id_] => 1200
                        [name] => Udf�rt arbejde
                        [type] => 0
                        [att_sumfrom] => 
                        [vatcode] => S25
                    )
.......
```

Sending the data

```
this.send = function(){
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url : this.url,
            data : this.data,
            timeout : this.no_timeout ? 0:this.timeout,
            cache : this.cache,
            dataType : this.dataType,
            type : this.type,
            global : this.global
        })
```

Comment: How do you send your data? Using `$.post`?

Comment: have updated question.. no with $.ajax

Comment: We need to know if the type is GET or POST. With GET there's a max length you may be hitting.

Comment: firebug return no errors.. the last part is just lost

Comment: have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit to how much data you can send per request, and depending on what method you're using. If you're using `POST` in PHP as the backend, take a look at PHP.ini [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits) and [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), where the former is script memory hogging and the latter is how much data can be sent through post requests. Defaults are 128M and 8M respectively.

If you're sending too much data that the server is not allowed to handle, the data will be cut as per instructions.

### Update

It is hard to debug without all the relevant code. Are you doing anything else on the backend before printing the array or are you just `print_r($_POST['data'])`ing? Because if you're not doing anything else, it still sounds like a memory setting on the server.

**Anecdote**

I remember a project where I had about 400 rows of data, each row had 7 columns (lots of text) that I sent through an AJAX object, and ~70 of the last rows was just cut out. After doubling the [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) all the data was being sent properly.

Comment: @clarkk Could you at least try a higher number and see if there's a difference?

Comment: both `memory_limit`and `post_max_size` is set to 128M and apache is restarted.. same problem.. last part is lost

Comment: @clarkk In firebug, under Net->XHR where your requests are being sent, can you tell me how many rows of data it says is being sent in the "post" tab and exactly how much size it takes?

Comment: ok.. the content-length is 41689.. how can I calculate the content-length of the js object?

Comment: As I can see.. all rows are sent

Comment: @clarkk Woah, 41689? And it's not returning URI too long error? Have you considered a different approach to the one you're currently using? Why are you sending so much data through javascript? If you want to transfer data between two PHP scripts, just store them in a `$_SESSION` variable instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9949/discussion-between-shadowscripter-and-clarkk)

Comment: but the data is sent as `_POST`.. How can you store the data in a `_SESSION`? the data is handled in javascript..

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related to your problem, but rather than attaching array items based on the array length, you should use the "push" function, which adds an item to the end of an array:

```
for(var key in obj){
    arr.push(key+' = '+obj[key]);
}
```